# How can you get a list of all addresses mentioned in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, address

I'd like to parse the blockchain in order to produce a list of all addresses that are mentioned in the blockchain.

I'd like to do this with a program, language agnostic.

Comment: Just use a tool: https://github.com/mrqc/bitcoin-blk-file-reader and modify the code as you like.

Comment: Several Bitcoin implementations index by address already. See libbitcoin-server, which allows you to query for all tx spending to/from an address. Unless you are interested in doing this yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

Addresses aren't mentioned in the blockchain. But you can calculate them based on the transaction scripts. In order to do this, you need to calculate the address from the [`scriptPubkey`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#General_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_output_of_a_transaction_-_Txout) of each transaction. To calculate the address you have to:

1. Determine whether it is a [`P2PKH`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#General_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_output_of_a_transaction_-_Txout) or [`P2SH`](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#General_format_.28inside_a_block.29_of_each_output_of_a_transaction_-_Txout), so you know what prefix to use: [List of address prefixes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes).
2. Calculate the `BASE58CHECK(HASH160(<prefix><scriptPubKey>))`